# Some of fn keys not recognized after upgrade

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, upgrade, gentoo

After upgrading my system (including kernel) I discovered that some of fn keys (XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown) are not recognized by **xev** and even **showkey**. Each time one of these keys is pressed the next message appears in **dmesg** output:

```
[ 429.202833] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x88 on isa0060/serio0).
[ 429.202847] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e008 <keycode>' to make it known.
```

I executed `setkeycodes e008 <keycode>` after that **showkey** started to show key code, however **xev** still cannot recognize that key was pressed.

One more detail which was discovered using **evtest** tool is that problematic keys generate only events with `value 2`:

```
Event: time 1430520388.854296, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 89
Event: time 1430520388.854296, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 2
```

At the same time all other keys generate events with `value 0`, `value 1` and `value 2`:

```
Event: time 1430520477.865671, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b0
Event: time 1430520477.865671, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP), value 1
Event: time 1430520477.865671, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1430520478.115796, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b0
Event: time 1430520478.115796, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP), value 2
Event: time 1430520478.115796, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1430520478.148696, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b0
Event: time 1430520478.148696, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP), value 2
Event: time 1430520478.148696, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1430520478.377785, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value  b0
Event: time 1430520478.377785, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP), value 2
Event: time 1430520478.377785, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1430520478.387684, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b0
Event: time 1430520478.387684, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP), value 0
Event: time 1430520478.387684, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

As I wrote above, a kernel upgrade also took place (3.19.3 -> 4.0.1). However now I encounter the same issue even on the old kernel. 
I guess the list of changes during update is necessary, so here I provide it: http://fixee.org/paste/zrm8kl2/

TIA